# Javascript window.print with page setup

Tags: javascript, printing

I am using window.print method to print a coupon. I want to change the page setup options. In page setup options, I want 2 things:

1. Print background(color and images) - it will be checked.
2. Shrink to fit page width - it will be unchecked.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done - security settings don't allow it